# Split string on backlash with trailing number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a string that I need to split. I've tried various split/replace methods but the trailing `'\03'` is treated like an octal `'\x03'`, so most of the 'usual' ways didn't work for me.

I've eventually come up with the following (which works, aside from the extra single quotation marks which I can easily remove) but I feel there must be a better/simpler way of doing this?

I have read `a` from a file.

```py
import re
a = "Delimited\string\03"
n = a.replace('\\', '-')
e = repr(n).replace('\\x', '-')
x = re.split('-', e)
print(x) # Gives: ["'Delimited", 'string', "03'"]
```

More info:

I was just testing/developing without reading from an actual file. Ultimately `a` will come from a file.

```
a = 'Delimited\string\03'
print(a)
print(a.split("\\"))
```

The above gives `['Delimited', 'string\x03']`. When I read from a file using the minimal example given in the answers, it works fine. I don't understand then why reading from file gives a different result because when I read from file `a` is `Delimited\string\03` from `print(a)` above?? So why does Python treat it differently?

Comment: Your error here is in how you form `a` in the first place. Use raw strings or escape your backslash. It's _treated_ like an octal because it _is_ an octal. See [string and bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: Secondly you are confusing backslashes used in Python's representation of a string with actual literal backslash characters present in the string. (Unicode code point 47)

Comment: I have read `a` from a file so I can't change to a raw string literal (tried various options to convert a variable to raw string literal but nothing worked). Updated question

Comment: *How* are you reading `a` from a file? What is the exact content of the file? What is your desired result? Make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me, but it was already mentioned from Brad Solomon

```
t = r"Delimited\string\03"
print(t.split("\\"))
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Per my edit of question, I have read `a` (`t` in your answer) from a file. So I can't add the `r` and the options I've seen to convert to raw string literal didn't give me the desired result.

Comment: What is in your file, because in my case it works:
a = open("Untitled.txt", "r").read()
print(a.split("\\"))

Answer (score 0):

And this doesn't work?
Untitled.txt: `Delimited\string\03`
Code:

```
a = open("Untitled.txt", "r").read()
print(a.split("\\"))
```

Output: `['Delimited', 'string', '03']`

Comment: Hmm...this is strange. If I read it in like you are doing, then it works. But, for my development I set `a = 'Delimited\string\03'`. In that case, I get `['Delimited', 'string\x03']`

Comment: Well for testing just set a to "Delimited\string\\03"

Comment: Or raw (r)in front of it :)